# Ionic $http request get not working with error data null status -1

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I use Ionic and Cordova framework for developing a mobile app, I've got the issue that can not use http get to request some url. For $http.get to some url that works fine, but some others not work and it response error like as

```
I/Web Console( 9179): {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[n ull],"url":"http://someexmaple.com/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"withCredentials":true}," statusText":""}
```

This issue only happens when I test on real mobile device and using adb debugging tool. But I tested on Browser and Genymotion virtual devices, both of them worked well for all url request.

So I've know idea with this response error. I think may be my device got problem.

Comment: had you installed whitelist plugin ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yeah I did. But it's still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've resolved my problem. I use inspect tool in Chrome, and move to network tab for watching the network packet, I see when I access to the url of site, it redirect me to another server port (instead of 80, it redirect to 443), I've noticed this because the 'Remote Address field' is the same address of url server, but port was changed. So I changed my $http.get request url from port 80 into port 443. And then it works, so I guess that when $http.get to the url but it didn't redirect to another port to get data, so it just response the null.